# Linq group by statement

Tags: c#, linq

I try to perform dynamic linq group-by query. The second linq statement should generate the same result as the first linq statement.
Can anyone show me why the second linq statement cant work?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("ProductName");

dt.Rows.Add("1", "aa", "TypeA");
dt.Rows.Add("2", "bb", "TypeA");
dt.Rows.Add("3", "cc", "TypeB");
```

The first linq:

```
var lotSum = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .GroupBy(x => new 
                             { id = x.Field<string>("id")
                               , product = x.Field<string>("ProductName"), 
                             }
                       ).ToList();
```

Second Linq  **// cant work??**

```
var gcol = new string[] { "ID", "ProductName" };
var gtype = dt.Rows[0].GetType();
var lotSum2 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(g => string.Join(",",  
            gcol.Select(c => gtype.GetProperty(c).GetValue(g, null)))).ToList();
```

Comment: The second LINQ is different from the first one - the second one doesn't project an anonymous type (which is the reason why the group by 2 fields works in the 1st LINQ, btw).

Comment: Wouldn't the second one just throw an exception as "ID" and "ProductName" are not public properties of the the DataRow type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID and ProductName are not properties of [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx), they are names of columns. You can access them using the indexer... gcol.Select(c=>g[c]), assuming g is a DataRow.